# Overriding System methods

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to modify a system method to add a condition into it.

The method is

```
System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
```

I'd like it to support other values such as "1.000" and "0.000".

Because for some reason a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` is throwing an exception about "0.000 is not a valid value for Boolean". And this is called from within the DataGridView's internal code... So I can't modify the call :/

I did not put those values nowhere as my TrueValue is "true" and my FalseValue is "false".

So that's why I want to override this method!

Any good way of doing so?

Comment: The cell is telling you the truth. 0.000 is not a valid value for Boolean. You should go find out how that value got there.

Comment: Can't you just change your `TrueValue` and your `FalseValue` accordingly?

Comment: To further emphasize John Saunders' point: if you don't know where the "0.000" is coming from, then you have a bug in your program. You have bad data. You can either fix that bug to prevent the bad data from getting into the system, or you can write a whole bunch of code that compensates for the bad data after it gets into the system. Your choice, but my experience has been that preventing the bad data is the easier of the two options.

Answer (score 3):

You can't override this method as it is declared `static`.

Write a wrapper around it (or an extension method on `Boolean`) that will implement your checks and if they pass delegate to it.

Comment: Is it possible to do so? Since this method gets called from the DataGridView code (that I can't modify since it's part of the framework) how would I call it? Thanks

Comment: @Tom - if it is called from within code you don't have control over, then I am afraid you are out of luck. The suggestion requires changes to the calling code. This is the kind of detail that you really, really, really should include in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify a method of the `Boolean` class so you can pass strings to it? If you want to parse strings, there are plenty of other ways to do it. For example, you can handle `1.000` like so:

```
using System.Float;

string foo = "1.000";
float result = Float.parse( foo ); 
value = ( result == 1.0f );
```

It would probably best if you wrote your own extension method. If you are using "1.000" as a value to represent true and that's the only thing you need it for, you should use a simple method like `return ( arg == "1.000" )`, or just use a Boolean in the first place. If you have multiple values that the string could handle, you'll have different logic. If you post some code and requirements we can probably help you more. :D